# Is there a way to fix the animation from overriding the initial translate

Tags: html, css

The initial positioning seems to be altered when the animation property is included. when the transform origin property is removed or added it will yield the same effect. The initial transforms are getting overridden by the animation.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section[id ^='sec'] {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: red;
}

#sec1 {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateX(100px) translateY(-80px)
}

#sec2 {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: aqua;
  transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-80px)
}

#sec3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
  transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(80px)
}

#sec4 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: purple;
  transform: translateX(100px) translateY(80px)
}

#sec5 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50;
  left: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: navajowhite;
  transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-10px)
}

#sec6 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50;
  right: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: teal;
  transform: translateX(100px) translateY(-10px)
}

#sec7 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: pink;
  transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(100px);
}

#sec8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: cadetblue;
  transform: translateX(50px) translateY(-100px);
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform-origin: initial;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: initial;
    transform: translateY(-120px);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: initial;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section id="sec1"></section>
  <section id="sec2"></section>
  <section id="sec3"></section>
  <section id="sec4"></section>
  <section id="sec5"></section>
  <section id="sec6"></section>
  <section id="sec7"></section>
  <section id="sec8"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using absolute positioning anyway, why not just apply the translates to the absolute values and then animate them as opposed to translating your already translated items? You're kind of working against yourself. (made the animation faster to make it more obvious, you can set it to your initial value)

```css
div {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section[id ^='sec'] {
  border-radius: 45px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: red;
}

#sec1 {
  right: -100px;
  top: -80px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: yellow;
}

#sec2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: -100px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: aqua;
}

#sec3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  left: -95px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
}

#sec4 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: -80px;
  background: purple;
}

#sec5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -100px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: navajowhite;
}

#sec6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -100px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: teal;
}

#sec7 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: 50px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: pink;
}

#sec8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 45px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: cadetblue;
  animation: float 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section id="sec1"></section>
  <section id="sec2"></section>
  <section id="sec3"></section>
  <section id="sec4"></section>
  <section id="sec5"></section>
  <section id="sec6"></section>
  <section id="sec7"></section>
  <section id="sec8"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question  but  I would also like to ask that is there a reason why the animation  is overriding the initial state as it should've not affected it's positioning as of my understanding

Comment: You're mixing transforms with positioning (on the container and your elements). You're asking your code to perform two conflicting actions. The transform-origin property isn't doing anything in this case (I updated my code, I should have removed it when I posted the answer) because it's the default value (`50% 50% 0`) that you've essentially overwritten with positioning attributes. 
Think of it this way: Imagine me asking you to stand to my left and also stand to my right. You can't do both at the same time so what would you do? You'd have to pick one or the other.